# Launching instruments from command line with iPhone simulator

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator, instruments

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line) question, how do I launch [instruments](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=instruments%20usage%20error%20:%20device%20failed%20to%20become%20ready%20for%20use.&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/InstrumentsUserGuide.pdf&ei=YGTXTrfXJqn74QSU0dzYDQ&usg=AFQjCNERXmPDcU_upgis4_dGmtSD3ueJiA&sig2=kjcVKlB3lsdFQsmlpZf9lQ) with iPhone simulator as a device.
I tried this:

```
$ instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -w iphonesimulator5.0 MyApp.app
```

But I get this error:

> Instruments Usage Error : Device failed to become ready for use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-w <deviceID>` is used only when you wish to specify a hardware device as the destination (the 'deviceID' here is the Identifier of the device, found in the Organizer of Xcode).

Instead of using `-w`, you can specify a flag during the build to force instruments to use iPhone.  Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349781/instruments-always-launches-ipad-simulator-for-universal-apps-with-automation-h).

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it as follows:
1.I created a template in which I was calling my UI Automation Main file that Triggers running all the scripts.
EX:
    //Main.js file will run auto.js scripts
    //auto.js is my main file in which I am running all the scripts
    //Main.js file
    #import "auto.js"
    auto.run();
//Now open terminal and run the following command.
1. Go to the directory where you saved your template
2.Copy the location where you simulator (full path) is
Than run the command below:
    instruments -t ./NameOfYourTemplate.tracetemplate /Users/swathyvalluri/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app

Note : Create a new file in the template and copy the contents into it what ever you want to put, otherwise it will look for Main.js file in your locally and will fail when  running it on another server.

Please let me know if you need more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Device id means here UDID of the device.

Also see the link below, it is very useful :
http://lemonjar.com/blog/?p=69