# How should I launch app installed iPhone device by terminal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instruments

I would like to launch app installed at iPhone device from terminal for development and testing.

I watched the below question and answer.

[Launching instruments from command line with iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340836/launching-instruments-from-command-line-with-iphone-simulator)

However I am using Mountain Lion and there are no such below file or path.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
```

Would you tell me about how to use such automation launching of Instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem a couple of days ago. Seems that starting from Xcode 4.4 Apple moved it to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate`

But in Xcode 4.5 I didn't find this directory as well. So I continued my search and found tracetemplate file in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate`

BTW, there's a nice [shell script](https://gist.github.com/3605692) which automates running stuff. All you need is to replace `INSTRUMENTS_TEMPLATE` with a proper path in `automation.sh`

Comment: I could do the way! I was very helped your answer. Your reference of shell script is helpful too :) Thanks a lot!